# What guidance for page file size and other system parameters for Oracle running on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, oracle

Slightly open ended question, but what are guidelines for configuring windows server 2008 running Oracle?

For example, should the paging file be kept small (1gb) if I've got 32gb of RAM in the server?
Are there any simple parameters to tweak?

Update: I've modified the configuration on one system to have no paging file on any disk as there is 32Gb of RAM in the system. This appears to work fine.  I'm wondering if there are any other parameters that could be modified

Comment: I tune all production database with the sole intent of them never realistically being able to utilize a swap file.

Comment: does this mean you give a very small swap file, or just make it so it never needs to use the swap file?

Comment: This question totally sounds like "read the documentation for me, I am too lazy". Oracle has guidelines in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle, Virtual Memory should be the double of the RAM available on the server for Oracle 10GR2:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15681/reqs.htm#BCFDACBF